# Match a sentence from a line in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following question. 
How do you match a sentence, which is surrounded by commas(,), but the sentences can vary in size and number of words. For example:

Hi,How are you,bye

Thanks, I am very good,bye

So I want to match "How are you" and "I am very good" 
I have tried something like

```
 $_ =~ /,([\w\s\w\s\w,])/;
```

but that seems very wrong and will "possibly" match 3 words separated by space.

Comment: The character class `[\w\s\w\s\w,]` doesn't do what you think it does. It matches a *single character* that is either a word character, white space, or a comma. Repeating items within a character class is superfluous, and this could be written equivalently as `[\w\s,]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't a simple `/,(.+?),/` do? Or `/,([\w\s]+?),/` if you want to be sure that you only have words and spaces?

```
my $str = "Hi,How are you,bye";

$str =~ /,([\w\s]+?),/;
print "$1\n";

$str = "Thanks, I am very good,bye";

$str =~ /,([\w\s]+?),/;
print "$1\n";
```

Comment: Oh Jesus. I got over-complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example:

```
if ($sentence =~ /,(.+?),/g) {
    print $1;
}
```

This will match the sentence and put the result into `$1`.
If you have multiple sentences:

```
while (<>) {
    while (/,(.+?),/g) {
        print $1;
    }
}
```

This is an example with input from the standard input and getting only the values between commas.

`(.+?)` will match everything which length is more than 0 and is not a comma. Because of the `()` it will be saved into `$1`.